# Flatlist displaying same items multiple times

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using flatlist to render data from api, the data are rendered and also displayed. But the problem is the items are displayed multiple times. I got  5 items from the api but those 5 items are repeating.

[image]

I have implemented as follows:

```
export default class FlatSpeakers extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [] }
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
       .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: res.data,
            })
        })
}
renderItem() {
    return (
        this.state.data.map(item =>
          <SpeakersDetails key={item.title} speakerD={item} />
        )
      )
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

I have implemented the  SpeakersDetails component as follows:

```
const SpeakersDetails = ({ speakerD }) => {

const { title, artist, thumbnail_image, image, url } = speakerD;
const {
    thumbnailStyle,
    headerContentStyle,
    thumbnailContainerStyle,
    headerTextStyle,
    imageStyle
} = styles;

return (
    <Card>
        <CardSection>
            <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={thumbnailStyle}
                    source={{ uri: image }}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={headerContentStyle}>
                <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
                <Text>{artist}</Text>
            </View>
        </CardSection>
    </Card>
);
 };
```

Comment: can you share the response from the api what you are getting ??? by console.log and share here. 
Because there is no error on the code, it may be due to that you are getting duplicate list there as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FlatList` iterates over `data` and call `renderItem` for each item in it, you are rendering the full list at every call, that's why you get items duplicated.

`renderItem` receives the current item as parameter, try change your function like this:

```js
renderItem({item}) {
    return (
          <SpeakersDetails key={item.title} speakerD={item} />
      )
}
```

Check the [`renderItem` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem) for further details, including additional parameters this function receives.

Comment: Can you explain how to implement the click to each item with its value?

Answer (score 1):

You should change you flat list callback for rendering FlatList item, to passing item into renderItem function. Now you are iterating over your state as many times as you got items from API call. Meaning 5 items per 5 times repeating.

Solution to your problem is to make call and make renderItem function like this below, you should pass item object into renderItem function:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem.bind(this, item)}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
```

Your renderItem function call should accept item object as argument and render UI from passed object:

```
renderItem(item) {
    return (
        <SpeakersDetails key={item.title} speakerD={item} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how I can I send the values to the another class ?

Comment: Sure, you can send values to another class, for example if another class extends from Component, you can set values over props. In this sample you can see setting label text via props, for "Mybutton" class, here:  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation

Comment: Can you please help me with this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067932/implement-onpress-on-flatlist-item

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const adList = useCallback((ad: any) => (
   <View>
      //Your item design
   </View>
), []);
```

Then In flat list use it like this

```
<FlatList keyExtractor={(contact, index) => String(index)}  data={ad_set} renderItem={adList} />
```

For more refer this link, and look at the bottom

https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration